# Reading a String from the console writed by a function in another class

Tags: java

I'm making a program with POO in Java, when a function finishes correctly it prints to the console:

```
System.out.println("Si sirvio")
```

If the function produces a error it prints the error.
I want that another function in another class can read what's in the console for determine the progress of a process compound by many functions.
I cannot use a Scanner because it will pause the program until the user input a String, in my case I want that the Scanner or whatever I should use reads whats on the console each time something is writed.

In other words, I want a Event Listener that reads what's in the console each time something is writed.

Comment: Are you allowed to use threads?

Comment: Yes, I'm allowed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try simple redirection of the System.out to some `OutputStream` and then check this stream for results:

```
import java.io.*;

class A {
    A() {
        System.out.println("instance of A created");
    }

    public void foo() {
        System.out.println("A::foo() succeeded");
    }
}

class B {
    static {
        System.out.println("static block in B executed");
    }

    public B() {
      System.out.println("instance of B created");  
    }
}

public class Test {

    private static void methodA() {
        System.out.println("Method A succeeded!");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();    
        System.setOut(new PrintStream(out));    

        System.out.println("Main output");
        methodA();
        System.err.println("1. Printed after `System.out` redirect:\n" + out.toString());

        A a = new A();
        B b = new B();
        a.foo();
        System.err.println("2. Printed after `System.out` redirect:\n" + out.toString());
    }
}
```

You will get this output in `System.err`:

```
1. Printed after `System.out` redirect:
Main output
Method A succeeded!

2. Printed after `System.out` redirect:
Main output
Method A succeeded!
instance of A created
static block in B executed
instance of B created
A::foo() succeeded
```

Comment: But the problem is that the method is in another class

Comment: It does not matter as the output is redirected for all/any attempts to write into `System.out`, please check the update.